# How to implement the Arbitrary instance for data type like this?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, quickcheck

I am new to Haskell, I am trying to write a test case to prove the associative law for Semigroup typeclass.

The data type define as followed:

```
newtype Combine a b = Combine {unCombine :: (a -> b)}
```

The implementation of Semigroup as followed:

```
instance (Semigroup b) => Semigroup (Combine a b) where 
  (Combine f) <> (Combine g) = Combine (\x -> f x <> g x)
```

I already wrote a associative test function

```
assocTestFunc :: (Eq m, Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
assocTestFunc a b c = (a <> b) <> c == a <> (b <> c)
```

and also defined a type alias like this:

```
type CombineAssoc = Combine String Ordering -> Combine String Ordering -> Combine String Ordering -> Bool
```

So in my main function, I can test it like this:

```
  quickCheck (assocTestFunc :: CombineAssoc)
```

However I am having a hard time to implement the `Arbitrary` instance for the `Combine a b` data type. 
Thanks advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the predefined instance for functions.

```
instance (CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary(Combine a b) where
   arbitrary = Combine <$> arbitrary
```

Comment: Additional remark: `Combine` either needs a `Show` instance, or must be used with `Blind`. Otherwise `quickCheck (assocTestFunc :: …)` won't type-check.

Comment: Not only that, but an `Eq` instance is also required.

Comment: yes, both of you are right, is it possible to give a full implementation of both Show instance and Eq instance for this data type? Thanks!

Comment: @PoppinDouble Not in general. How would you print a function `Integer -> Bool`? You can add a dummy instance like `instance Show (Combine a b) where show _ = "<<fun>>"` but it would not be very informative. You might achieve better results if you are more specific on what `a,b` are.

Comment: @chi yes, your are right, for the Show instance, it will be not that informative in this way, how about the Eq instance, how could we implement == for a function type?

Comment: @PoppinDouble I'm afraid you can't for the same reason: to compare two functions one needs to evaluate it on all its inputs (possibly infinitely many). I'd suggest you use quickcheck to test it only on a few random points. I.e. instead of checking `f==g` you need to check something like `forall (\x -> f x==g x)`. This means that you can't use your nice `assocTestFunc` for that. It is a pity, but we can't avoid computability limitations. I can't see a better approach at the moment.

Comment: @chi Thank you so much! Yes, I think i will just write several unit test. Thanks again! :)